# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to make a post request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, fetch, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to make a post request using fetch. Normally when I use `npm start` to start my server it works just fine. But with webpack dev server it gives me this error:
[image: Error in chrome console]

This is my server side code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const mockAPIResponse = require('./mockAPI.js')

const PORT = 8081

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY
const baseUrl = 'https://api.meaningcloud.com/sentiment-2.1'

const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
var path = require('path')
const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static('dist'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('dist/index.html')
        //res.sendFile(path.resolve('src/client/views/index.html'))
})
app.post('/api', async(req, res) => {
    console.log("you key is", apiKey)
    const enteredUrl = req.body.url;
    const apiUrl = baseUrl + '?key=' + apiKey + '&url=' + enteredUrl + '&lang=en'
    console.log(apiUrl)
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
    try {
        const fetchedData = await response.json()
        console.log(fetchedData)
        res.send(fetchedData)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
    }


})


app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send(mockAPIResponse)
})

// designates what port the app will listen to for incoming requests
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error)
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}!`)
})
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "evaluate-news-nlp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest",
        "start": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
        "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
        "build-dev": "webpack-dev-server  --config webpack.dev.js --open"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Alaa",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "2": "^3.0.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.7",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "sass": "^1.45.1",
        "webpack": "^4.44.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^5.1.2",
        "file-loader": "^6.1.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "jest": "^26.5.3",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "sass": "^1.45.2",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "supertest": "6.1.3",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.5",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1"
    }
}
```

Webpack dev server works fine until I try to make the post request. I tried different versions of webpacks, webpack dev server, node-fetch but still getting the same error.
How can I solve this error?

Edit: I think the problem has something to do with the fact that webpack dev server runs on port 8080 while my express server runs on 8081. When I checked the network tab for the request this is what's shown:
[image: API fetch request in the network tab]

And this shows up after the error:
[image]

***Edit: I was able to solve the problem by running webpack dev server and then opening another terminal and running npm start to start my express server. Is this how it's supposed to work normally? Because the tutorial I was following was working fine with only webpack dev server***

Comment: Please post your `package.json` file

Comment: The server code in Node isn't directly affected by your webpack server. Check the Network tab and see if there are more details on the request error. It's possible there is an issue with CORS. Is your frontend also on 8081?

Comment: @Lucas I think CORS is working fine because without webpack dev servers everything runs well. I have added screenshots for the network tab after the error. Please have a look at it. Can the problem be that webpack runs on port 8080 but my express server runs on 8081?

Comment: Yes. That’s what I’m referring to. Look in the Payload/Preview/Response sub-tabs in the Network tab to confirm. You probably need to manually allow requests from the different origin

Comment: Oh after reading your edit was the issue just that you weren’t running the express server? If you want, you can make it part of an npm script to run both

Comment: @Lucas yes turns out only running webpack dev server isn't enough. I thought it would also do what npm start does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error happens because the express server isn't running. Run `npm start` to start the express server